# Is it a problem that my laundry drain protrudes above ground level?

Tags: plumbing, drain, exterior, crawlspace

My plumber just moved the laundry's washer drain location and this is the picture from the outside:

[image]

It was re-connect to the old drain pipe and go into crawl space.

My question is: Does it look right like that when the pipe is somewhat high on the ground and sticking out?

I mean some kids would have been not smart enough and step on it, right?

Is it code violation or no? The city is **Tacoma, WA**.

Comment: The location must be “ hack city” wow that looks like crap. Did he do it for a 6 pack of beer?

Comment: Does it go to septic or sewer, or?? Quite possibly a code violation, just how bad of a violation.... Let alone lack of protection, foot traffic, freezing... Was it concealed/protected originally?

Comment: @jsotola This is in Tacoma, WA. I updated the question.

Comment: @Jack It goes to sewer. It was like that in the beginning, meaning the pipes were exposed outside. But I am questioning about how far and how high the 90 degree turn is now. Kids playing around could mistaken it as a play structure and hopping all over it, right?

Comment: I would never put anything past kids

Comment: I'm confused why a drain would be outdoors in a freezing climate. This looks like something from the 19th century. You can always raise grade a couple inches to cover the pipe, but....

Comment: I think the question is moot. This doesn't meet modern code for reasons completely unrelated to the concerns raised in the question. You can't run drains outdoors in freezing climates. Everything should be below frost depth.

Comment: You have to dig it up and re-plumb it correctly. Forget about fixing it because of "code," just fix it because one day it's going to freeze up, or like you mentioned, some kid is going to bust it up, and your washing machine is going to dump water all over the inside of your house. Things can _meet code_ and still not be **right**. You need to get some siding back on that house too, or there will be another whole set of problems to contend with as well.

Comment: @EdBeal  He did it after a 6 pack of beer.

Comment: @GregNickoloff That is what I was thinking. I am trying to get the plumber back to fix it. BUT there was no problem on freezing for 2 years (last year snow storm was bad). The way it looks: the pipe is angled down so there shouldn't be any "standing" water at a given time for freezing right? I am thinking about "physics" at this point. Agree it is code violation. I am just trying to push it NOW (in Jan) or can wait few more months.

Comment: Yeah... so far, so good. It's hard to tell what the angles are from the picture. As long as everything is going downhill and the water goes quickly, you have a fighting chance. If the drain slows down or plugs up, it could freeze pretty quickly under the wrong conditions. Anything above the frost line can freeze as soon as it gets really cold so an extended cold snap and a few loads of laundry might be enough to choke out the drain with ice. Maybe just do "hot" laundry in the winter until you can get at fixing it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have it redone and buried.  Though it is unsightly, the real problem is not appearance but the exposure, not only to the elements but to human influence.  It needs to be trenched and placed below freeze level.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0):

The plumber could have dug that down further. You can hit that with a lawn mower which should not be the case.

Given that there is a concrete slab there, it is the best and cheapest option.

Comment: "Given that there is a concrete slab there, it is the best and cheapest option." What "it" is the best and cheapest option?

Comment: Cheapest option being run the pipe outside of the house and then into the ground.  Otherwise plumber would have to jackhammer the concrete foundation, dig out the pieces and dirt underneath said concrete, replace the plumbing, and put new concrete down all while making sure that the house didn't collapse. Extra cost of the concrete is reinforced with rebar.

Comment: Pretty sure that the general consensus is that while this was the cheapest option, it's most certainly not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Well two things.   Laundry drain has to exit to the sewer.   There are revisions for grey water but I don't need to get into them because he didn't even try to come close to the requirements.

Then the biggie in my mind is that you are not allowed to bury drainage PVC, whether it be laundry or sump pump or whatever.   Definitely a hack job and code violation.

(Won't be a big deal until it backs up and you get water damage on a floor.   But if you ever tried to sell the house this is one of those things where you for sure would have to fix it first.   And more important potential buyers would think they just did whatever with this house - this hack job could cost you 5-10k.   Why I said it's probably not a huge deal... until you think about it.)

... And come on he couldn't run it to a toilet?

Side Note:  Did he just fill a cavity in your house with spray foam?

Comment: Filled the cavity with spray foam. Decorated the lawn with spray foam. SPRAY FOAM ALL THE THINGS!@!!!!!